# Transposing wide to long in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am a newbie to Python.  I need to transpose from df1 to df2 in pandas. Can someone show the codes that transpose data from wide to long?  Thanks

df1:

```
  id     1/22/20    1/23/20 1/24/20 1/25/20
   a        1       2       3       4  
   b        3       4       5       6
   c        5       6       7       8
```

df2:

```
  Date      a       b       c
  1/22/20   1       3       5
  1/23/20   2       4       6
  1/24/20   3       5       7
  1/25/20   4       6       8
```

Comment: set id as index and then transpose: `df.set_index("id").T.rename_axis("Date")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [df.set_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [df.T](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) and [df.rename_axis](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html)

```
df = df.set_index('id').T.rename_axis("Date", axis=1)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
Date     a  b  c
1/22/20  1  3  5
1/23/20  2  4  6
1/24/20  3  5  7
1/25/20  4  6  8
```

Answer (score 1):

[T](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html#pandas.DataFrame.T) or [transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) can be used.

```
df.set_index('id').T
id  a   b   c
1/22/20 1   3   5
1/23/20 2   4   6
1/24/20 3   5   7
1/25/20 4   6   8
```